# How to create a Heatmap in R for one column of data?

Tags: r, heatmap

I have the following data in R - a column showing the names of cities and a column showing growth of incomes. I would like to create a heat map using this data. 
How could i do this? Is it even possible to create heat maps for one column of data

say data is something like:

```
City           Data
New York       780
LA             982
DC             111
Boston         893
Chicago        989
```

And continues on many rows. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Just for clarification, what exactly would the heat map show?

Comment: Do you mean a coropleth map?

Comment: What would be on the x and y axes?

Comment: Heat maps are for visualisation of differences between some probes ex. gene expression in 3 cancer cell lines vs 3 normal cell lines.To be honest, standard barplot will fit well for your data :)

Comment: I agreew with the comments. You first have to think about what questions you want to answer, then you decide which plot is more suited

Answer (score 1):

It may make sense to have a heatmap for one column, if you want to visualize how close or how far away  e.g. cities are regarding that 1 item measured.

```
# your data
df <- data.frame(
  City = c("New York", "LA", "DC", "Boston", "Chicago"),
  Data = c(780, 982, 111, 893, 989)
)

# calculate distance/dissimilarity matrix (a dist object)
distance <- dist(df$Data, diag = TRUE, upper = TRUE)

# transform to matrix and set the labels
distanceM <- as.matrix(distance)
rownames(distanceM) <- df$City
colnames(distanceM) <- df$City

# create heatmap
heatmap(distanceM)

# or without reordering and without dendrograms
heatmap(distanceM, Colv = NA, Rowv = NA)
```

type `?heatmap`  for more details

Please let me know whether this is what you want.

Comment: Hi thanks for your help. I think there is something wrong with my data. Your code works. But my data set is huge and so something bizarre is happening!

Comment: My pleasure. Could you be more precise about what is going wrong? I imagine it could be with the names of the cities overlapping. Something like that? It would help if I knew the number of rows.

Comment: Hi - Thanks! The number of rows in my data is 625. I am just really confused. I think I don't understand heat maps well